# Which version of .NET, if any, must the user install to run my WPF app?

Tags: installation, .net-4.5, installshield, setup-deployment, prerequisites

I'm making a setup program for an app I wrote. I'm using the Visual Studio setup template, using InstallShield. The wizard (not Merlin, unless it's Olsen, maybe) asks me about required software:

[image]

My app is built on a machine with both Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 installed. The app uses .NET Framework 4.5

Do I need to select "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Full package" in the "Project Assistant > Installation Requirements" section of the Installshield wizard above, or...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will be in your WPF project settings and app.config.  WPF was released in .NET 3.0 as I recall so you might be targeting 3.0, 3.5, 4.0 client, 4.0 full, 4.5 (full) or 4.5.1.  If 3.0 or 3.5 you might have an app.config that says run on CLR 2 or 4.   From there you tell InstallShield what kind of gate checks it should perform (if any).  It might not be the end of the world if you just install the app and when you click the shortcut you get a friendly message telling the user what version to install.

Comment: I am targeting .NET 4.5, according to project properties. Are you saying that if I choose nothing from the "does your app require any software" collection of checkboxes that the user will be prompted to install .NET 4.5 if they don't have it? That would probably be best, anyway. If I check "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 full package" would it install it regardless (replacing an existing installation) or just silently say "never mind" if it's already there?

Comment: You'll want to test this in a lab VM....  in the days of .net 1.0, 1.1, 2.0 you'd get a really nasty dr Watson error if you clicked on an .EXE and you didn't have .NET. Worse if you were installing a service or web app where there is no "click".  So installers evolved to either a) do a gate check and abort or b) install it.   As .NET evolved the error messages of running an .EXE are prettier and it'll often prompt you to go download and install.  The screen you are looking at isn't defining a prereq installation it's defining a gate check.